# Bootstrap 4 Grid System col class taking different width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have one div that is a row and inside a few more rows with two col classes each. But what is strange is the first two col-3 classes take different width than the next two col-3 classes which makes the element un-aligned one on top of another. The code is bellow

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row p-3 w-100">
  <h5 class="text-center w-100">Color Legend</h5>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 w-100">
      <i class="far fa-circle circle px-2"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-9 w-100">
      <p>Not visited topic</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 w-100">
      <i class="far fa-circle circle px-2" style="color:#016fc9;"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
      <p>Visted topic</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <i class="far fa-circle circle px-2" style="color:#00bfa5"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
      <p>Visted topic, pop-up question <strong>successfully</strong> answered.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <i class="far fa-circle circle px-2" style="color:#f44336"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
      <p>Visted topic, pop-up question <strong>failed</strong> after visting.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a screen of the result
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRgqd.png

Comment: Remove the `w-100`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are breaking the `.row` > `.col` hierarchy. Meaning `col` should have `.row` as a parent and vice versa. In your case, you have `.row` as parent and child, which is why you had to give `.w-100`. Please try the below code.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row p-3">
  <div class="col-12">
    <h5 class="text-center">Color Legend</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        <i class="far fa-circle circle px-2">I</i>
      </div>
      <div class="col-9">
        <p>Not visited topic</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        <i class="far fa-circle circle px-2" style="color:#016fc9;">I</i>
      </div>
      <div class="col-9">
        <p>Visted topic</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        <i class="far fa-circle circle px-2" style="color:#00bfa5">I</i>
      </div>
      <div class="col-9">
        <p>Visted topic, pop-up question <strong>successfully</strong> answered.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        <i class="far fa-circle circle px-2" style="color:#f44336">I</i>
      </div>
      <div class="col-9">
        <p>Visted topic, pop-up question <strong>failed</strong> after visting.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```